# New String or get parameter from http request every time?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, request

is it better to instantiate a string with the value of an http request parameter or to read the parameter from the request every time in nested if conditions?

For example :

```
if( request.getParameter( "pageMove" ) != null ){
    if( request.getParameter( "pageMove" ).equals( "N" )){
    ;;
    }
}
```

vs.

```
String pageMove = request.getParameter( "pageMove" );
if( pageMove ) != null) {
    if( pageMove ).equals( "N" ) ){
    ;;
    }
}
```

Which is more efficient in terms of performance and memory management?

Thanks

Comment: In this case, not much. First, you are not instantiating, but accessing with `getParameter()` method, which returns you a reference to variable normally. Second, when you store it in variable, you are kinda saving one call to `getParameter()`. And presumably saving stack space with one variable, instead of two when two calls to `getParameter()` should return same object.

Comment: In your place, I would not think of such tiny insignificant things, if you don't receive enough load. When you get hitting 1000s-10000s transactions per second to your jvm, then you will probably be using different code anyway :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why use two if-statements at all?  You can re-word the inner if-statement to the following so the `null`-check isn't required:

```
if ("N".equals(request.getParameter("pageMove"))) {
    // ...
}
```

To answer your question, though, you're over-optimizing. The extra amount of memory in use from not storing the value in a variable is insignificant and will be eligible for garbage collection whenever it goes out of scope.

In this scenario, I'd **always** prefer readability over a negligible performance increase.